# Display SoftwareBitmap on image control without saving to file in UWP C#

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, uwp, uwp-xaml

Is there a way to display SoftwareBitmap on Xaml Image control without saving the SoftwareBitmap to file? I want to have a quick way to display the SoftwareBitmap after edit.

Answer (score 5):

> I want to have a quick way to display the SoftwareBitmap after edit.

Currently, the Image control only supports images that use BGRA8 encoding and pre-multiplied or no alpha channel. Before attempting to display an image, test to make sure it has the correct format, and if not, use the SoftwareBitmap static Convert method to convert the image to the supported format.

```
if (softwareBitmap.BitmapPixelFormat != BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8 ||
    softwareBitmap.BitmapAlphaMode == BitmapAlphaMode.Straight)
{
    softwareBitmap = SoftwareBitmap.Convert(softwareBitmap, BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);
}

var source = new SoftwareBitmapSource();
await source.SetBitmapAsync(softwareBitmap);

// Set the source of the Image control
imageControl.Source = source;
```

You could alse use `SoftwareBitmapSource` to set a SoftwareBitmap as the ImageSource for an ImageBrush. For more please refer to [**Create, edit, and save bitmap images**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/imaging).